# How can I find the source of water leaking over a window?

Tags: leak

We have a new build home. It is a year old. Two times in the last year we have had heavy rain/wind that have caused one of our windows to leak from the top down. The water seems to come in at the sheetrock/window connection. It does not leak on the bottom. The water is very dirty looking. It leaks bad enough that it causes a puddle on the floor.

We have tried to reproduce the leak without any luck. We have soaked it with a hose right on the window, as well as above. Also, when it snows, and rains, it doesn't leak. Only during heavy rain/wind. We recently had over a foot of snow that melted. No leaks. We have also gone in the attic to look for any signs of water. None were found.

Does anyone have any tips on how we can identify where the water is getting in at? We do have pictures of the home during construction which show flashing was used around the window. The outside exterior of the home is stucco.

[image: a busy cat][1]

[image: a busy cat]
[2]

[image: a busy cat][3]

Comment: Within a year there should be a warranty from the builder. But if you cannot recreate the problem they might not agree that there is a problem.

Comment: A picture from the outside showing the window and everything above to the eve line might help.

Comment: Please edit to tell us more about the building envelope and drain plane. What else was done to weatherize before siding?

Comment: Isherwood, the outside is stucco. A stucco wrap was done before the stucco was applied.

Comment: When you soaked it with a hose, did you spray the water at an almost-horizontal angle? Or was the water coming down mostly vertically?

Comment: MMathis, we basically sprayed the water straight at the house/window for several minutes. We used a hose attachment to get a higher pressure to spray the area.

Comment: I suspect the problem is at the stucco joint above the window.  The problem is water runs, meaning where it is entering may not even be close to where it's coming back out.